# SQL Server - table seems to be blocked

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, transactions, locking

I attempted to save a graph of objects using NHibernate. The save failed due to a not-null constraint violation.

I am now finding that a table in the database corresponding to one of the objects in the graph now appears to be locked. I cannot query it. Whenever I try, it just sits there doing nothing until I cancel the query. This has been the case for about half an hour.

In the save code, the transaction is first committed and then disposed.

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT against the database gives 0.

Any ideas a) What's going on and b) How can I get the table back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@TRANCOUNT` is scoped to the [current connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx).

Assuming you have sufficient permissions on the server.

```
select hostname,program_name, spid,text  from master.sys.sysprocesses 
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) s
WHERE open_tran>0
```

gives any connections with currently open transactions along with the last text executed by that connection. I'm using sysprocesses for the reasons [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/06/29/why-i-still-need-sysprocesses.aspx).

If the above query shows your culprit then you can get the spid and use `kill <spidnumber>` to unceremoniously roll it back.You might want to consider setting [XACT_ABORT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) on for future queries so errors won't leave transactions open.

Comment: Invalid object name 'sysprocesses'. What schema is it in?

Comment: For SQL2005+ it is in the `sys` schema but the `sys` is optional for backwards compatibility so sounds like you haven't got permissions to view it. Can you do something on your application side to close the connection? Also do you have a similar problem with @DOK's suggestions?

Comment: If I can't view it, noone can! It's my database... DOK's suggestions ran okay.

Comment: @Martin: XACT_ABORT > 'Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.' Is this not the default behaviour???

Comment: @David - No that's not the default behaviour. Sorry try `select * from master..sysprocesses WHERE open_tran>0`. That will give you the spid of the session with the open transaction (say 53). If you are sure that is the correct session you can use `kill 53` to unceremoniously kill it and roll it back.

Comment: And to check that it is the right spid you can use `declare @handle varbinary(100) select @handle = most_recent_sql_handle from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=53 select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@handle)` (Replace 53 as appropriate)

Comment: @Martin - your comment about using select * from master..sysprocesses and kill 53 is the one that's working for me. Would you mind editing answer to reflect this?

Comment: @David - Will do. The last one gets you the text last executed by connection so you could verify you were killing the right one.

Comment: @Martin - thank you for the tip about XACT_ABORT. I feel like I need to handle the problem in a higher app level, so I'm catching exceptions in the repository code and rolling back the transaction instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database, try running `sp_lock` to see who has the table locked.

**Edit**: That will return records with several columns of information described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx). One of those columns is `spid`. You can use `sp_who` (or `sp_who2`) to see who is logged in, and look for the `spid` holding the lock.

If you have "view server state" permission, you can also use `sys.dm_tran_locks`.

Comment: sp_lock tells me I have two KEY locks, a PAG lock and a TAB lock. How do I find out who the user is? And how do I remove the locks?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you properly disposed of your session? That's usually the cause of such problems...

Answer (score 0):

try running this:

```
SELECT
    r.session_id AS spid
        ,r.cpu_time,r.reads,r.writes,r.logical_reads 
        ,r.blocking_session_id AS BlockingSPID
        ,LEFT(OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid),50) AS ShortObjectName
        ,LEFT(DB_NAME(r.database_id),50) AS DatabaseName
        ,s.program_name
        ,s.login_name
        ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS ObjectName
        ,SUBSTRING(st.text, (r.statement_start_offset/2)+1,( (CASE r.statement_end_offset
                                                                  WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
                                                                  ELSE r.statement_end_offset
                                                              END - r.statement_start_offset
                                                             )/2
                                                           ) + 1
                  ) AS SQLText
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests                          r
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions                      s ON r.session_id = s.session_id
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) st
    WHERE r.session_id!=@@SPID
```

it will tell you who is blocking your query

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't return any rows!

Comment: then there isn't any activity on that database, remove the `WHERE` and you will see the row for this actual query.  Open multiple SSMS windows, run a slow query in one window and then quicky change to this window and run this query, you can see rows then

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of any other DB-specific behaviors, you should rollback the transaction immediately after an error. That shouldn't leave anything locked.

Comment: I've worked (as a developer) with databases for years and I always thought transactions were rolled back automatically if the database errors. Funny time to find out how wrong I was!

Comment: Thank you Diego. I have updated my repository code accordingly and now the table isn't locked after database errors.